# Prove the following $x^2−y^2=(x−y)(x+y)$

Tags: proof-verification

I'm going through the book Calculus by Michael Spivak, not sure on how to go about the first problem. If anyone can just go through it with a solution I think I can handle myself from there. Thanks.

Prove the following:

$x^2−y^2=(x−y)(x+y)$

Comment: Try using the FOIL rule.

Comment: $(x-y)(x+y)=(x-y)x+(x-y)y=\dots$

Comment: Oh yes distribution! Thank you @JMoravitz

Comment: If I recall correctly the first chapter of Spivak's Calculus is devoted to the axioms of the real numbers and they are listed as P1, P2, ... Just use them successively to expand the RHS

Comment: I wasn't sure if I was doing it right thank you @mathbeing

Answer (score 9, accepted):

$(x-y)(x+y)=(x-y)(x)+(x-y)y= (x^2-xy)+(xy-y^2)=x^2-y^2+ ( xy-yx)=x^2-y^2+0=x^2-y^2$. (note that near the end we used $xy=yx$).

Comment: Does it matter with side of the equation you choose to start proving from? @jorge

Comment: no it doesn't, because you proved that the two things are equal either way.

Answer (score 6):

So, you'd use the distributive law and cancellation by additive inverse: $(x-y)(x+y) = x(x+y) - y(x+y) = x^2 + xy - xy - y^2$

Comment: yeah, and commutativity of both addition and multiplication is used various times.

Answer (score 3):

Treat $x^2-y^2=0 $as a quadratic equation in variable $x$. Use $x=\frac{-b\pm\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}$ so that

$x=\frac{0\pm\sqrt{0+4y^2}}{2}=\pm y$

So $x^2-y^2=(x+y)(x-y)$

Answer (score 1):

Alternately, $(x^2-y^2) = (x-y)^2-2y^2+2xy = (x-y)^2 -2y(y-x)=(x-y)^2 +2y(x-y) =(x-y)[(x-y+2y)]=(x-y)(x+y)$